# Selenium Driver Service not found exception

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium

I am new to Selenium. While going through simple tutorial, I got stuck with above exception. The error is related in initialization itself:

```
[TestInitialize()]
    public void MyTestInitialize()
    {
        var capabilitiesInternet = new OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilitiesInternet.SetCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings",true);
        WebDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();            
    }
```

The error looks as [here](http://picpaste.com/_err-cmBaKmlb.JPG) while the dlls are present as seen [here](http://picpaste.com/err-Orqa0UNW.JPG).
Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

you are missing IEDriverServer.exe in your directory. 
You can get them from here: 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebDriver.IEDriverServer.win32

Or directly from here:

http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.46/